# Automatic Slide Transition Loop in CSS

Tags: css

Which CSS code i need to add to my Code to get the nonstop Slider Animation? I want the Pictures slides automatically one by one when not on hover with a selected time frame between each slide.The Hover function is already added to the css so it doesn't need to add again and you can be run here easily to check it out.

> Please Run the Code in Full Screen mode.

HTML:

```css
   /*  Exstyle Header Design */
#main-row102
.wrapper {
  width:auto;
  position:fixed;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}



.col-xs-3 {
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
  height:340px;
  background:transparent;
  z-index:1;
}

.wrapper-background {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index :0;
  transition: background 5s;
}

.wrapper:hover .col-xs-3 {
  background:none;
}
.wrapper:hover .col-xs-3:hover {
  background:red;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(1):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/30/19/03/railway-station-3714297_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}

.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(3):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/10/10/05/04/locomotive-60539_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(5):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/05/20/07/cloister-2041063_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(7):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/11/28/10/30/honor-guard-67636_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(1):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/30/10/03/dance-1940245_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}

.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(3):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/06/22/03/49/diveevo-140542_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(5):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/11/08/48/model-2303361_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(7):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/15/09/00/man-845847_960_720.jpg");
  z-index:-1;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-row-102"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `+` and not `~`

Comment: I am reading for the third time, but to be honest, I have no idea what the question is. Can you try to explain with a bit more detail what exactly do you want to achieve. Try to be precise. Where exactly do you want a slideshow to happen? On background, behind all of the "cells" or in each individual div/cell?

Comment: @TemaniAfif i will try Now thank you for the Reply )

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac i want to achieve this >> www.extyl-pro.ru  .... Thank you for reply )

Comment: @TemaniAfif Using + not a Good idea, even the motion Transition stopped working!

Comment: considering your logic you need + to target only the next element on hover .. the ~` is targeting more than you think, using `~` you see only 2 images in total and you have 8

Comment: @TemaniAfif The Hover effect is working Fine, i just want to add automatic Transition. the example is in the Link you see.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  you can check the example here. www.extyl-pro.ru

Comment: I have just opened example you have provided. What you want to achieve would be much much easier (and definitely preferred way if you want fine grain control over what's going with those backgrounds) with javascript than with pure css. It's probably not impossible but it would require a lot of css hacks. Do you also want 2 or 3 different photos per one element (like in the example)?

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac yes absolutely if this is very simple and easy with java then let's try it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the same architecture for background and start animation when you hover columns.

```css
#slider {
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/* Hide everything out of slider */
#mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 240px;
}

/* The list of the images */

#slider ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#slider li {
    width: 980px;
    height: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -245px; /* Initial position  (out of slider) */
    list-style: none;
}

.slider-img {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#slider li.firstanimation {
   animation: cycle 20s linear infinite;
}

#slider li.secondanimation {
   animation: cycletwo 20s linear infinite;
}

#slider li.thirdanimation {
   animation: cyclethree 20s linear infinite;
}

#slider li.fourthanimation {
   animation: cyclefour 20s linear infinite;
}

/* Animation */

@keyframes cycle {
   0%  { top: 0px; } /* When animation starts we already see the first image */
   5%  { top: 0px; } /* Start position */
   20% { top: 0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } /* From 5% to 20 % (3 secs) image visible */
   25% { top: 245px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 20% to 25% (1 sec) entrance of the image*/
   26% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } /* Return to the starting position out of mask */
   90% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   95% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; } /* From 95% to 100% (1 sec) – entrance */
   100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes cycletwo {
   0%  { top: -245px; opacity: 0; } /* The starting position out of the mask */
   20% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; }/* Start move from 20% */
   25% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   30% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }  /* From 25% to 30% (in 1 sec) — entrance*/
   45% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }   /* From 30% to 45% (3 sec) image is visible */
   50% { top: 245px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 45% to 50% (1 sec)— exit */
   95% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }   /* Return to the starting position out of mask */
   100%{ top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@keyframes cyclethree {
   0%  { top: -245px; opacity: 0; }
   45% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; }
   50% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   55% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   70% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   75% { top: 245px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   76% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -245px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@keyframes cyclefour {
    0%  { top: -245px; opacity: 0; }
    70% { top: -245px; opacity: 0; }
    75% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
    80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
    95% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
    100%{ top: 245px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
                        <div id="mask"> 
                            <ul>
                                <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
                                    <img class="slider-img"  src="https://coverfiles.alphacoders.com/455/45585.jpg"/>
                                </li>

                                 <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
                                    <img class="slider-img"  src="http://www.tuellaneinfantschool.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/foxes-header.jpg"/>
                                 </li>

                                 <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
                                    <img class="slider-img"  src="https://wallpapers.pub/web/wallpapers/fox-animal-wallpaper-hd/1500x500.jpg"/>
                                 </li>

                                 <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
                                    <img class="slider-img"  src="https://coverfiles.alphacoders.com/484/48440.jpg"/>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>
                         </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so Much Irina ) на нашем языке, большое спасибо.

Comment: please take a look at this Question also >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343817/how-to-add-simple-progress-bar-and-how-to-link-with-the-background-function?noredirect=1#comment93567149_53343817